# Jhipster projects keep trying to use wrong database

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jhipster

I'm trying to develop some test projets using jhipster but I'm facing a problem.
I've choosen to use H2 in memory in develop mode and postgresql for production.
When I start the project in dev mode, it looks for postgres db and also for a db with the wrong name.
Also, every single project looks for the same db, but I can't find the properties with that db name.
I tried a projects using postgres also in dev mode and it works, but using always that database!
I tried to debug every single row but I couldn't find where the code find that url.
I found out that it sets it in DataSourceBuilder url.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Also, add code to make it clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I found out the solution to my problem. Can I explain it here just in case someone will have the same problem in the future?

Comment: Yes please add an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I had set some spring datasource configurations in my Windows environment variables. 
That's why each project ignored its own properties.